# Split row names and group them for output table in R

Tags: r, split, grouping

I have the output table of a logistic regression model, which I would like to output as a table. At the moment my estimates table looks like as follows:

```
row.names         estimate  CI
bmi.cat[0,18]
bmi.cat[18,25]
bmi.cat[25,30]
is_female
region_code1
region_code2
region_code3
age_at_base
```

I would like to split the rownames and group them to get:

```
variable      level    estimate  CI
bmi.cat      [0,18]
             [18,25]
             [25,30]
is_female
region_code    1
               2
               3

age_at_base
```

Any ideas how can I perform that?

Answer (score 0):

First, having a data sample would be handy. However, without it I'll suggest this:

The package `sjplot` is great at formatting regression output. For example, the regression model:

```
m<-lm(hwy~displ+fl, data=mpg)
library(sjPlot)
sjPlot::tab_model(m)
```

Gives this after passing the model parameters to `sjPlot`:
[image]

You might also need to specify each row as a different predictor, depending on the analysis plan you have.

`sjPlot` has many formatting options, as well, to help you dial in your preferences. See the [vignette here](http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/articles/sjtlm.html).

Comment: Thank you. But I am adding odds ratios and floating absolute risks to the output as well, so I do not want to directly report the model output.